# App crashes after Xcode upgrade to 4.5. Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my class I have a `dispatch_queue_t` property declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

Then in my init method I do:

```
- (id)initWithServerUrls: (NSString*)serverUrls
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.my_send_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }

    return self;
}
```

In Xcode 4.4.1 it worked and did not cause any problems (the app tested + in the appstore).
Now after I upgraded to Xcode 4.5 the app crashes with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** and Xcode gives me a warning on that line saying:

**Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable; object will be released after assignment**

Apple updated the compiler in Xcode 4.5 from LLVM 4.0 to LLVM 4.1 but I have no clue why my code is crashing right now.

I stepped through the code and the crash happens just after that line.
Do you have any ideas what can be wrong and how can I fix it?

**SOLUTION:**

I managed to get it working with both SDKs. I just added:

```
#if OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t queue; // this is for Xcode 4.5 with LLVM 4.1 and iOS 6 SDK
#else
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t queue; // this is for older Xcodes with older SDKs
#endif
```

Hope someone finds it useful

Comment: self._queue = dispatch_queue_create ... does it fix it? - adding the "self."

Comment: No, still the same, crashes. Warning is also there.

Comment: than "Assigning retained object" it means the result from dispatch_queue_create(... and " to unsafe_unretained variable" it means the _queue. And if the @synthetize doesn't solve ( because it is on Constructor) than somehow need to manipulate the dispatch_queue_create( returned value, could you post that object, what he returns?

Comment: When I put a breakpoint just after the dispatch_queue_create and examine what is inside the _queue it says "Class - error:unknownclass". But I don't know cause this can be just this crappy Xcode debugger.

Comment: no more idea, except if you change the assign to retain of ARC: strong @property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t queue; but maybe that implies to change your code in other part too

Comment: After changing it to "strong" app crashes in different place but I don't know where and why. I updated the original question with the log messages.

Comment: @matheszabi why would it help? The error is unrelated, read the error message (you too, OP!) The problem is that when you use a copied property, the new compiler emits code referring to a helper function (objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy()) which is not found on the devicd itself, only in the development sysroot, hence the dynamic loader can't resolve that symbol and fails to launch the app. Upgrade your device to iOS 6.

Comment: assign is the same thing as unsafe_unretained, by the way.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks! But how can I make it work on iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Comment: @RafałSroka I don't think that's quite possible with Clang 4.1. You can eiher downgrade Xcode, or... (fill in)

Comment: The issue is that `dispatch_queue_t` is an object in iOS6, but not an object in iOS5. There are several fixes for this that I've listed below. None require downgrading the compiler (though I do recommend downgrading the SDK to the version you are targeting).

Comment: Some clues might be found at this discussion: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/352

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, if your target platform is 5+, then I strongly recommend building with the iOS 5 SDK. Building with a later SDK and setting the "target" can work, but has lots of problems (not the least of which is that you get no compiler help to find places that you've used unsupported methods). So answer 1: You need iOS 5, build against iOS 5 and this shouldn't matter.

In iOS 6, `dispatch_queue_t` is an ObjC object. This is a great improvement. It means you can just create `strong` properties for it and ARC will take care of the rest. If you target iOS 6, this should just work.

If you need to build the same code for iOS 5 and iOS 6, then you need to know which is which so that you can put in the memory management when you need it and leave it out when you don't. The correct test to use is `#if OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC`. Remember, this is a *compile-time* check. It's only applicable for dealing with code you want to write against different SDKs. For a given SDK, the behavior will aways be one way or the other.

Regarding the "unsafe_unretained" versus "assign" confusion: They are the same thing in this case. "assign" only applies to non-objects. "unsafe_unretained" is what "assign" is converted to when applied to objects. And in iOS6, `dispatch_queue_t` is an object.

One more workaround, particularly if you really do want to keep the old memory management code while building with the iOS 6 SDK. You can pass `-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0` to the compiler. This will opt-out of the new model. But I would recommend this as a last resort. For details, see `os/object.h` in the SDK. (Cmd-Shift-O, object.h)

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot!

Comment: I need to support both versions of the iOS so I will use the test you proposed. The only thing I don't get now is how should I replace the "@property (nonatomic, copy) CustomBlock completedBlock;" so it does not crash the app on iOS 6. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Note that if you're just *running* on both platforms, you should just build for iOS 5. You only need this if you need the same code to compile differently depending on what platform you're building for. If you need to replace the `@property` line, just wrap it in the `#if` check (if the variable is set, then use `copy`. If the variable is not set, use `assign`.)