# Error while compiling firebase based project in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to use Firebase with Objective-C.

I get following error when trying to compile my project. My code looks fine. The issue is originated from `Firebase.h`:

> Error:  property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object
>   type in file `FConfig.h`

it is showing error in the following line of the file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t callbackQueue;
```

`FConfig.h` is included in `Firebase.h`.

Comment: Do you have a circular import with `Firebase.h`?  Where are you importing the header into your class?  Are you using the latest version of the Firebase SDK?

Comment: I changed the deployment target to iOS 6.0 and now the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Engineer here,

Sounds like the problem here has to do with older versions of the iOS SDK, where `dispatch_queue_t` is not an object in iOS 5, but is an object in iOS 6 (due to ARC being more fully rolled out).

Therefore, in iOS 5 and prior, we would need to use:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t callbackQueue;
```

Rather than in iOS 6+:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t callbackQueue;
```

More info on this is in this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511976/app-crashes-after-xcode-upgrade-to-4-5-assigning-retained-object-to-unsafe-unre).

As iOS adoption on new versions is generally fairly high, Firebase doesn't support iOS 5 and before (and generally won't fix issues with iOS6), as it's estimated that the share of devices running these OS's is [relatively small](https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) (~5%). Is there a particular reason you're targeting iOS 6 (or earlier)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary fix for it:

In your podfile where You see

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
```

comment user_frameworks!

```
target 'Runner' do
  # use_frameworks!
```

and go to path /ios of the project

run

`pod install`

and cheers